# How to pass the subject name from certificate to create an x509 user in MongoDB via command line using --eval

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell

---

I have a shell script that grabs the subject name. 
I then pass it to my mongo instance to create the x509 user.
However, when I authenticate I see that the SUBJECT environment variable that got passed in has stripped spaces and the CN=// is also gone.

shell script to grab subject from cert 
`SUBJECT=$(openssl x509 -in server-cert.pem -inform PEM -subject -nameopt RFC2253 | grep subject | sed 's/subject=//')`

command line to execute js code with env variable saved from SUBJECT. 
`/usr/bin/mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile server-combined.pem admin --eval "var SUBJECT = '$SUBJECT'" createUser.js`

contents of my createUser.js

```
    addUser(SUBJECT);
    function addUser(SUBJECT) {
     print(SUBJECT);
     db.getSiblingDB("\$external").runCommand({ createUser:SUBJECT,roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "test"},{ role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }],  writeConcern: { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 }});
     db.getSiblingDB("\$external").auth({mechanism: "MONGODB-X509", user: SUBJECT})}
```

expected

```
CN=\ 10.1.1.1,OU=A,O=PP,ST=PA,C=US
```

actual

```
CN= 10.1.1.1,OU=A,O=PP,ST=PA,C=US
```

Error message from mongo logs

```
   Error: 18 Username " CN= 10.1.1.1,OU=A,O=PP,ST=PA,C=US" does not match the provided client certificate user "CN=\ 10.1.1.1,OU=A,O=PP,ST=PA,C=US"
```

Build environment

Linux Ubuntu

Mongo v2.6

```
    docker pull mongo:2.6
    docker build .
```

Dockerfile

```
    FROM mongo:2.6 
    ADD createUser.js /opt/
    ADD scriptuser.sh /opt/
```

Comment: Mongo 2.6 is ancient.  You might find better help using Mongo 4.2 instead.  A lot has changed between these versions.

Comment: The js file has several commands.  Can you tell if the first call createUser is completing successfully before calling auth?  It may be beneficial to work the commands out manually before trying to automate them.

Comment: I don't have a choice in the mongo version. Yes when debugging i have a print statement that prints the subject correctly from scriptuser.sh, but it looks incorrect when printing from inside the JS file, print(SUBJECT);

Comment: but is the command 'createUser' completing successfully before moving to the next command 'auth'?

Comment: I believe so, given that the error mongo throws complains about my created user vs. the one it pulls directly from the client certificate user. Also i can use the mongo shell and run 'use $external' and 'show users' and i see the user I created with the 'createUser' command.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, it does fail to createUser, I should see a response back from mongo with a { ok, 1} status and I do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a file env.js where I save the SN to. 
So when calling the command to connect to mongo, I load both files which sets up the proper SN and loads my createUsers.js

```
/usr/bin/mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile server.pem admin env.js createUser.js
```

Then inside of my js file createUser.js I have modified to

```
function addUser() {
SUBJECTJS=SUBJECTJS.toString().replace("CN=","CN=\\");
print(SUBJECTJS);
printjson(db.getSiblingDB('\$external').runCommand({ createUser: SUBJECTJS,roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "sda"},{ role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }],  writeConcern: { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 }}));
printjson(db.getSiblingDB("\$external").auth({ mechanism: "MONGODB-X509", user: SUBJECTJS }));
} 
addUser();
```